# Count query in php

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, sql

I would like to seek some help with my query problem in php...I want to do is count all (atic) with the same number and if the specific (atic) is equal to 7 my Insert query will execute to that (atic).

The problem is my count query wont work as i wanted....and execute my insert query to all aic even the count is not = 7.

[image]

current code:

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("cant connect!");
mysql_select_db("klayton") or die("cant find database!");
$total = NULL;
$count = "SELECT count(t.atic) as '$total', t2.name FROM app_interview as t, tb_applicants as t2 WHERE t.atic = t2.aic GROUP BY t.atic";
$query = mysql_query($count) or die (mysql_error());
while($rows =mysql_fetch_array($query)){
if($query = 7){
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO afnup_worksheet (faic,fnl_name,interview,fregion,ftown,funiq_id,fposition,fsalary_grade,fsalary,dateinputed) SELECT DISTINCT atic, atname,(SELECT sum(inttotal) FROM app_interview t2 WHERE t2.atic = t.atic)/7, region, town, uniq_id, position, salary_grade, salary, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP FROM app_interview t GROUP BY atname HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT atic)");
}
}
?>
```

Comment: first of all use `if($query == 7)` instead of `if($query = 7)`

Answer (score 0):

`$query = 7` means you are assigning value 7 to variable `$query`

In order to compare you have to use double equal sign `==`

or triple equal signs `===` for same data type.

Comment: i change it to == now but my query wont filter specific (atic) if its = 7...can you help me with this?

Comment: mick with a total of 7 (aic) should be execute but its not working as i planned.

Comment: Sorry I am not really an SQL expert. `SELECT count(t.atic) as '$total'` Why did you put Total like that

Answer (score 0):

```
if($query = 7)
```

means you assign $query is 7 and it will always true and always executed, you can try this

```
if( $query == 7 )
```

That means if `$query` value is equal to `7` or not